# Google API SignIn HostedDomain cleanup problem

Tags: xamarin.ios, google-signin

We implement the Sign-In on iOS using the Google API in our project. Customers must have a possibility to select the HostedDomain to limit the allowed account pull to the single domain.

```
SignIn.SharedInstance.HostedDomain = "domainName.com";
```

works perfectly.

The problem is when we want to Logout the user and log in it back with unrestricted HostedDomain

```
SignIn.SharedInstance.HostedDomain == null; // <-Default Value
```

When I try to set it to

```
SignIn.SharedInstance.HostedDomain=string.empty;
```

I filter everything.

When I try to set it to null

```
SignIn.SharedInstance.HostedDomain=null;
```

I get the exception.

Calling:

```
SignIn.SharedInstance.Dispose();
```

doesn't help.

The question is: How is possible to reset the HostedDomain filtering to the initial stage  - allow everything without of the app restart.

Our implementation based on Xamarin iOS native, but we see the same problem in Swift or Objective-C.

The wrapper for the Gooogle SDK we use:
Xamarin.Google.iOS.SignIn